# Generate dynamic web pages and urls in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, url

New to the whole web programming scene, usually stick to offline applications.
On this page of my site I'm using gridview to pull items from an SQL database.

That's all fine and dandy, but here's where I get confused.
Upon selection of an item I want to navigate to another page which is generated with information from my SQL database, I'm fine here, I have a template for the page that pulls information for the page based on the selected item using a get property for a WHERE itemname= sql command.

However, currently, the site goes like this. http://exampleurl.com/items.aspx

I would like users to be able to link to a specific item. So upon selection it should generate a url for that item.

http://exampleurl.com/items.aspx?=selecteditemname

Comment: It's hard to figure out if you don't show the code that generate the <a> tag. You'll have to append the item name to the link somehow. You url should look more like: http://example.com/item.aspx?name=[itemname]. To get it back just use Request.QueryString("name")

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.
I'm just being a tard as usual.

Set the column in your gridview to a hyperlink

```
navigateurl='<%# String.Format("../Default.aspx?id={0}", Eval("ColumnId"))%>'
```

Open up the code for the page you are redirecting to and set your WHERE in the gridview to

```
Request.RawUrl.Split("=")(1)
```

This will get everything after the '=' in your url.
i.e.

http://exampleurl.com/Default.aspx?id=123

`Request.RawUrl.Split("=")(1)` will return '123'

OR

```
Dim item As String = Request.Url.Query
Dim query As NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(item)
Dim id As String = query["id"]
```

Comment: I would use HttpUtility.ParseQueryString instead of splitting it myself.

Comment: Added code for parsing query strings for future reference by others.